# if time is between two times then return true

Tags: php

i write code in php for return true when time is between to 2 time

```
$camp_curr_time = date("H");
$time_from ='19';
$time_to = '10';

if($time_from<=$camp_curr_time && $time_to>=$camp_curr_time)
{
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

but problem is if now time is 9 its return false . but this time is between time from and time to .help me please
or any change above code when return true between 2 times
we use time from 01 to 24 hour we not use am or pm

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$camp_curr_time = (int) date('G');
$time_from = 19;
$time_to = 10;
$eleven = 23;

if(($camp_curr_time >= $time_from && $camp_curr_time <= $eleven) || $camp_curr_time <= $time_to) {
    echo 'true';
} else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

So the `true` time range is 19-23 and 0-10.

Comment: not work i set time to time 3 to 6 but our time is 10 its show me true

Comment: Setting `$time_from` to 3 and and `$time_to` to 6 would give a `true` range of 3-23 and 0-6. This code is designed to cross midnight. Please explain the `true` range you're trying to achieve.